# matlab code optimization - clustering algorithm KFCG

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, cluster-analysis

## Background

I have a large set of vectors (orientation data in an axis-angle representation... the axis is the vector). I want to apply a clustering algorithm to. I tried kmeans but the computational time was too long (never finished). So instead I am trying to implement KFCG algorithm which is faster (Kirke 2010):

> Initially we have one cluster with the entire training vectors and the codevector C1 which is centroid. In the first iteration of the algorithm, the clusters are formed by comparing first element of training vector Xi with first element of code vector C1. The vector Xi is grouped into the cluster 1 if xi1< c11 otherwise vector Xi is grouped into cluster2 as shown in Figure 2(a) where codevector dimension space is 2. In second iteration, the cluster 1 is split into two by comparing second element Xi2 of vector Xi belonging to cluster 1 with that of the second element of the codevector. Cluster 2 is split into two by comparing the second element Xi2 of vector Xi belonging to cluster 2 with that of the second element of the codevector as shown in Figure 2(b). This procedure is repeated till the codebook size is reached to the size specified by user.

I'm unsure what ratio is appropriate for the codebook, but it shouldn't matter for the code optimization. Also note mine is 3-D so the same process is done for the 3rd dimension.

## My code attempts

I've tried implementing the above algorithm into Matlab 2013 (Student Version). Here's some different structures I've tried - BUT take way too long (have never seen it completed):

```
%training vectors:
Atgood = Nx4 vector (see test data below if want to test);
vecA = Atgood(:,1:3);
roA = size(vecA,1);

%Codebook size, Nsel, is ratio of data
remainFrac2=0.5;
Nseltemp = remainFrac2*roA; %codebook size
%Ensure selected size after nearest power of 2 is NOT greater than roA
if 2^round(log2(Nseltemp)) < roA
    NselIter = round(log2(Nseltemp));
else
    NselIter = ceil(log2(Nseltemp)-1);
end
Nsel = 2^NselIter; %power of 2 - for LGB and other algorithms
```

MAIN BLOCK TO OPTIMIZE:

```
%KFCG:
%%cluster = cell(1,Nsel); %Unsure #rows - Don't know how to initialize if need mean...
codevec(1,1:3) = mean(vecA,1);
count1=1;
count2=1;
ind=1;
for kk = 1:NselIter
    hh2 = 1:2:size(codevec,1)*2;
    for hh1 = 1:length(hh2)
        hh=hh2(hh1);
%        for ii = 1:roA
%            if vecA(ii,ind) < codevec(hh1,ind)
%                cluster{1,hh}(count1,1:4) = Atgood(ii,:); %want all 4 elements
%                count1=count1+1;
%            else
%                cluster{1,hh+1}(count2,1:4) = Atgood(ii,:); %want all 4
%                count2=count2+1;
%            end
%        end
        %EDIT: My ATTEMPT at optimizing above for loop:
        repcv=repmat(codevec(hh1,ind),[size(vecA,1),1]); 
        splitind = vecA(:,ind)>=repcv; 
        splitind2 = vecA(:,ind)<repcv;
        cluster{1,hh}=vecA(splitind,:); 
        cluster{1,hh+1}=vecA(splitind2,:);
    end
    clear codevec
    %Only mean the 1x3 vector portion of the cluster - for centroid
    codevec = cell2mat((cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:,1:3),1),cluster,'UniformOutput',false))');
    if ind < 3
        ind = ind+1;
    else
        ind=1;
    end 
end
if length(codevec) ~= Nsel
    warning('codevec ~= Nsel');
end
```

Alternatively, instead of cells I thought 3D Matrices would be faster? I tried but it was slower using my method of appending the next row each iteration (`temp=[]; for...temp=[temp;new];`)

Also, I wasn't sure what was best to loop with, for or while:

```
%If initialize cell to full length
while length(find(~cellfun('isempty',cluster))) < Nsel
```

Well, anyways, the first method was fastest for me.

## Questions

Is the logic standard? Not in the sense that it matches with the algorithm described, but from a coding perspective, any weird methods I employed (especially with those multiple inner loops) that slows it down? Where can I speed up (you can just point me to resources or previous questions)?

My array size, Atgood, is 1,000,000x4 making `NselIter=19;` - do I just need to find a way to decrease this size or can the code be optimized?

Should this be asked on CodeReview? If so, I'll move it.

## Testing Data

Here's some random vectors you can use to test:

```
for ii=1:1000 %My size is ~ 1,000,000
    omega = 2*rand(3,1)-1;
    omega = (omega/norm(omega))';
    Atgood(ii,1:4) = [omega,57];
end
```

Comment: Perhaps to remove a loop, I can repmat the codevec and then subtract (instead of if statement), then whichever are negative separate those indices?

Comment: Does the minimal example you posted above work for you? If I copy/paste it all I get an `Index exceeds matrix dimensions` error in the `cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:,1:3),1), ...`

Comment: Whoops, take out the initialization of the `cluster` variable. See edit. Still am not certain that the code does what I think it does...

Comment: Perhaps to remove with repmat:
`repcv=repmat(codevec,[size(vecA,1),1]);`
`splitind = find(vecA>repcv);`
`splitind2 = find(vecA<=repcv);`
`cluster{1,hh}=vecA(splitind);`
`cluster{1,hh+1}=vecA(splitind2);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest issue is re-iterating through all of vecA FOR EACH CODEVECTOR, rather than just the ones that are part of the corresponding cluster.  You're supposed to split each cluster on it's codevector.  As it is, your cluster structure grows and grows, and each iteration is processing more and more samples.

Your second issue is the loop around the comparisons, and the appending of samples to build up the clusters.  Both of those can be solved by vectorizing the comparison operation.  Oh, I just saw your edit, where this was optimized.  Much better.  But `codevec(hh1,ind)` is just a scalar, so you don't even need the repmat.

Try this version:

```
% (preallocs added in edit)
cluster = cell(1,Nsel);
codevec = zeros(Nsel, 3);

codevec(1,:) = mean(Atgood(:,1:3),1);
cluster{1} = Atgood;

nClusters = 1;
ind = 1;
while nClusters < Nsel
    for c = 1:nClusters
        lower_cluster_logical = cluster{c}(:,ind) < codevec(c,ind);
        cluster{nClusters+c} = cluster{c}(~lower_cluster_logical,:);
        cluster{c} = cluster{c}(lower_cluster_logical,:);
        codevec(c,:) = mean(cluster{c}(:,1:3), 1);
        codevec(nClusters+c,:) = mean(cluster{nClusters+c}(:,1:3), 1);
    end
    ind = rem(ind,3) + 1;
    nClusters = nClusters*2;
end
```

Comment: By the way, something seems wrong with Nsel.  Do you really want half as many clusters as datapoints?  cluster size of 2 points on average?  That seems strange.

Comment: Whoa, thanks for making it clear, I see the error in my ways of the first issue... Like I said in the question, I'm not sure how much I can compress this data; 0.5 is too high, thanks for pointing that out... Nsel=0.2*total gave elapsed time of ~373 seconds... Any way to preallocate `cluster`?

Comment: Sure: cluster = cell(1,Nsel);  You're right, that might make a big difference

Comment: Oops, preallocate codevec as well, and my time for 1e6 points drops to 28 secs.  Post edited to add preallocation

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand how cluster is being filled - doesn't this loop overwrite cluster? (1st time through for loop: `nClusters=1`,`c=1`, so `cluster{2}` and `cluster{1}` are filled.)(2nd time through: `nClusters=1`,`c=2`, so `cluster{3}` and `cluster{2}` are filled.) - so 2 is overwritten?? ... Some clusters are empty, which is why I am asking.

Comment: nClusters represents number of valid cluster from the previous iteration.  So nothing is ever in cluster{nClusters + c}.  It's a safe place to place the second generated cluster.  In your example, you can't have c=2 with nClusters=1.  The second loop will have nClusters=2, c=1 and c=2.  For c=1, we'll overwrite cluster{1} and cluster{2+1}, then for c=2 cluster{2} and cluster{2+2}.  Think of it this way: we start with, say, 4 clusters.  After the iteration, we want 8.  The lower half of the 4 stay in 1:4, and the upper half of the 4 end up in 5:8.  Nothing prevents empty clusters in this algo.

Comment: Oh I see, the for loop won't go past nClusters... To me, the algo does prevent empty clusters because if you take the centroid (by the mean), something will always be below and above - unless you take the mean of 1 vector I guess. But looks like your code is all good - a few more checks and I'll accept it.

Comment: Exactly: look at the stats of the cluster sizes at the end, and you'll see from the distribution that some *should* be zero.  Use this: `counts = histc(cellfun('size', cluster, 1), 0:10); bar(0:10, counts, 'histc');`